# python requests library, not downloading file

Tags: python

Folks,  Trying to download a remote file and scrape through it.  Using conventional requests or urllib is throwing this into the output file:

```
{
  "code" : "not_found",
  "error" : true,
  "message" : "No service found for this URL."
}
```

using curl/wget or browser works fine...

```
>>> import requests
>>> 
>>> url = "http://download.foo.com/filename.zip?function=download"
>>> r = requests.get(url)
>>> print r.content
{
  "code" : "not_found",
  "error" : true,
  "message" : "No service found for this URL."
}
```

Is this something the web server is preventing me from?  I dont want to shell out to curl, would still like to stay inside the python interpreter :)

Thanks!

Comment: Can you tell us the precise URL? Otherwise, we're only guessing.

Comment: Do `r.status_code`, `r.reason`, or `r.headers` reveal anything interesting?

Comment: Some sites filter by user agent.