# Is "code": "not_found","message":"..." unique to Python Requests?

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, http-status-code-404, python-requests

I'm trying to track down the source of a 404 error message which looks like this:

```
{
  "code": "not_found",
  "error": true,
  "message": "Cannot find web property with name [the name of the AWS EC2 host]"
}
```

[This appears to be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19992419/python-requests-library-not-downloading-file) the format generated by Python's Requests library.

However, our application has no Python (it's NodeJS), so I'm confused. However, it's deployed on a server outside our direct control, so who knows? (We can't reproduce the error on our hardware).

So, is this error definitely originating from some Python application?

And for bonus points: any idea what "cannot find web property" means? It sounds like Google Analytics terminology.

EDIT

The full response headers:

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Age:113430
Cache-Control:public,max-age=315360000
Connection:close
content-encoding:gzip
Content-Length:141
content-type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Sat, 08 Aug 2015 11:13:28 GMT
Expires:Thu, 31 Dec 2037 23:55:55 GMT
Server:nginx
Vary:Accept-Encoding
Via:1.1 varnish
x-error-code:not_found
x-error-message:Cannot find web property with name ec2-54-66-245-125.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com
X-Powered-By:Express
x-socrata-region:production
X-Varnish:1908749315 1908744066
```

Comment: No, this has nothing to do with the Python `requests` module. Looks like [data.colorado.gov](https://data.colorado.gov/api/views/wumm-7awb/doesnotexist) has a REST API that generates responses like that. It seems they're running [Socrata](https://github.com/socrata-platform/soda-fountain), so you may want to look into that stack. I suggest you have a look at the response headers of your 404, if you can.

Comment: Oh that's interesting - this is also a Socrata instance. Want to turn your comment into an answer?

Comment: I'd rather not actually - there's so little to go on (for me) that this was just some wild guess. You've got much more context, so if you think you've tracked down the origin of that response, feel free to post an answer yourself. Glad I could point you in the right direction though ;-)